# Cannot use bicepparam file in Azure deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am trying to use a `.bicepparam` [parameter file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameter-files?tabs=Bicep) in my Azure CLI deployment and I get an error of `unrecognized template parameter 'using './test.bicep'`. My deployment does work if I use a traditional ARM parameter JSON file.

Is this a problem with my syntax or is this a bug? It's almost as if the Azure CLI isn't aware of bicepparam files. I haven't seen anyone else with this problem other than one person for GitHub issue [111296](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/111296) I created regarding the Bicep parameter file documentation, so it's very possible it's some syntax problem on my end.

Below is my test Bicep template, Bicep parameter file, and the command I used. I am trying this on macOS, but I also have this problem when using Windows 11. I expect this template to return JSON showing the output for **combinedValue** to be `Hello World!'`. Here is additional information.

- macOS Ventura 13.4.1
- Azure CLI 2.49.0
- Azure CLI Bicep 0.18.4

### test.bicep

```
param value1 string
param value2 string

output combinedValue string = '${value1} ${value2}'
```

### test.bicepparam

```
using './test.bicep'

param value1 = 'Hello'
param value2 = 'World!'
```

### Command (zsh)

```
% az deployment group create --name test --resource-group test-resouce-group --template-file test.bicep --parameters @test.bicepparam
unrecognized template parameter 'using './test.bicep'

param value1 '. Allowed parameters: value1, value2
```

Comment: have you tried with `--parameters test.bicepparam` => just removing the `@`

Comment: I agree with @Thomas - your bicep and bicepparam files look fine. The problem is in your command. using `az deployment group create -g innerloop -f .\test.bicep -p .\test.bicepparam` works great for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[This was answered by @Thomas and @GordonBy in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76560363/cannot-use-bicepparam-file-in-azure-deployment?noredirect=1#comment134990617_76560363).]*

The `@parameters.json` syntax is not used when deploying a .bicepparam file with Azure CLI. Instead, just specify the filename as so:

```bash
% az deployment group create --name test --resource-group test-resouce-group --template-file test.bicep --parameters test.bicepparam
```

This is different from a traditional JSON ARM parameter file, where you *do* use the `@` symbol before the filename. As per Thomas' comment below, the @ symbol loads the contents of the file, so it's effectively the same as typing the inline parameters on the CLI. Since that's not what we want to do with a .bicepparam file, we don't need use the @ symbol.

Comment: You could also add something like that in your answer:  the @ symbol is necessary to load json file. In CLI 2.0 it is used to load the contents of the file. It is effectively the same as supplying a JSON string by loading the file. This is from https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5899#issuecomment-425998938

Comment: ty, very helpful, and the original error message, so not helpful.  :-)